# move_uploaded_files() doesn't move file without error

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to allow my website to upload files to the server. Here is my code so far:

form_upload.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="file_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

file_upload.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
          echo "Did not store file.";
      }else{
          echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Everything works fine, but when I go to look on my server, I don't see the file in the `/uploads` folder. When the form is submitted, the php file echos this:

Upload: square-big-button.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 9.875 kB
Temp file: /tmp/phpyhjzZF
Stored in: uploads/square-big-button.jpg

Of course, `Temp file` will always be different.

What is going on? Why is it saying it was uploaded when it wasn't?

SOLUTION:

I just needed to add a `../uploads/` as the dir.

Comment: try http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp :) may be your dir "upload" not "uploads"

Comment: @RakeshSharma the code is my question is literally copy and pasted from there

Comment: same copy then may be your dir "upload" not "uploads"

Comment: try move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: @RakeshSharma my directory is named `uploads`.

Comment: What about folder permissions on your folder ?

Comment: @Chancho I have it set to `777`

Comment: then why if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) { also check @Chancho comment it's was my next comment :)

Comment: is uploads dir and file_upload.php file are on same location?

Comment: @RakeshSharma that was a typo, but that shouldn't even matter because it never moves the uploaded file to the `/uploads` dir.

Comment: @RakeshSharma no. uploads is one level above file_upload.php

Comment: then use "../uploads/"

Comment: @RakeshSharma: w3fools' upload handling script doesn't even qualify as crap. it is highly dangerous code, badly written, and should never be even acknowledged as existing. the entire site is garbage.

Comment: @MarcB I know and agree. I just need to figure out why this basic functionality isn't working. On my working site, I have much more secure file uploader.

Comment: @RakeshSharma jynx! lol.

Comment: @rob: basic debugging: did you check the return value of m_u_f()? it returns false on failure.

Comment: @MarcB it returns true

Comment: @RobAveryIV have you tried "../Uploads/"?

Comment: @rob: then the move worked, and it just went somewhere other than what you're considering. e.g. start building your destination path in a variable and echo it out, so you can see EXACTLY where you're telling php to put the file. And note that your script allows a malicious user to scribble a file of their choosing ANYWHERE on your server. at least it's limited image filename extensions, but still... w3fool's stuff is incredibly dangerous. never EVER blindly use their code.

Comment: @Charles that doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to give a correct path of location where you want to save . also check dir have writable permission
if you uploads dir is one up level us `../` to move up and so on

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

if uploads dir is on your server root try

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: this doesnt work because "../uploads" isnt a dir. Using /uploads is in the root directory.

Comment: hmmmmm, all ado about nothing, I feel ashamed. I must solve this now.

Comment: so uploads dir is on your root?

Comment: if its in the root won't $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/", work?

Comment: @RakeshSharma, hmm, I don't know that method, but I will try that this evening, if it works, then learned something new. Rob said thought that the uploads is in root, so we have to get to the "root" of the problem :-)

Comment: @Charles yeah but i think Rob get the miss and he also good rate on stack so let's move what's next

Comment: @RakeshSharma just tested it out now, and it works for me, if it doesn't work for Rob, then I'm really outta options.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I used `../uploads/`. I don't what I did last time to not make it work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Since you said your uploaded file is in the root, and you are sure of it, then this should work.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/" .   $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Just tested it out now on my localhost, and it has moved the file to my uploads directory located at the root of my web directory.

Comment: Are you saying he should up the comment?

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine here, maybe you have placed the uploads directory in the wrong place. The uploads directory should be in the same directory as the files, or you should use the right relative path as ../uploads.
Can you tell us the path for each files/folder?

Also, this line seems to be wrong.

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
```

it should be verifying the uploads directory.